# Non-optimal breadth-first search implementation

Tags: java, data-structures, breadth-first-search

I'm currently working on an assignment to build a word ladder which gets from a word to another by changing only one letter at a time [& still maintaining it being a real word, of course].

I think the problem lies in this method - finding the link between two words by traversing a tree using breadth-first search. I've implemented the algorithm by aping the description given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Algorithm), however, the solution give in tests is not optimal. An example [it can obviously miss out sayer, payer & manor]:

```
Discovery: link found, 6 words
layer
sayer
payer
mayer
mayor
manor
major
```

The ideal scenario would be:

```
Discovery: link found, 3 words
layer
mayer
mayor
major
```

I've tried debugging this code, but as it involved a lot of looping, it's not a very feasible way of trying to solve the problem.

A few pointers:

- It generates the graph as it goes [connectionLink()], saving time.
- The class this method is in stores all the Nodes [points in the graph] in a Hashtable with the key being the word & the object being the object of the word.
- A Node store a list of Nodes it's connected to [by being on character different], a boolean for whether it's been visited or not & the word itself as a String.

  ```
  /*
   *  @return     String      Returning a String listing words traversed to the goal
   *  @param      fW          First word
   *  @param      sW          Second word
   */
  public String discovery(String fW,String sW){
      String result="Discovery: no link found";
      StringBuffer links=new StringBuffer();
      int i=0;

      Queue<Node> queue=new LinkedList<Node>();               //  Breadth first search uses a queue
      queue.add(hash.get(fW));                                //  Root of the tree, tree generated on the fly

      while(!queue.isEmpty()){
          Node current=(Node)queue.poll();
          if(!current.getVisited()){      
              current.setVisited(true);                       //  Making sure it's only cycled once

              if(current.getWord().equals(sW)){               //  Goal state
                  while(current.getParent()!=null){           //  Generating the list words traversed
                      i++;
                      links.insert(0,"\n"+current.getParent().getWord());
                      current=current.getParent();
                  }
                  result="Discovery: link found, "+i+" words"+links.toString()+"\n"+sW;
                  System.out.println(result);
                  break;
              }
              else{
                  connectionLink(current.getWord());              //  Finding connections

                  for(Node node:current.getConnections()){        //  Getting the connections of the Node
                      if(!node.getVisited()){                     //  If child Node isn't visited, add to queue
                          node.setParent(current);                //  Sets parent as Node just left
                          queue.add(node);                        //  Adding Node to queue
                          //  System.out.println("Discovery: adding "+node.getWord()+" to queue. Child of "+node.getParent().getWord());
                          //  System.out.println("Discovery: current queue - "+queue.toString());
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      clearVisited();
      return result;
  }
  ```

Node [has standard getters & settings also]:

```
public class Node{
    private String word;                    //  The data of the Node
    private Node parent;
    private LinkedList<Node> children;  //  Holds children
    private boolean visited=false;


    public Node(String word){
        this.word=word.toLowerCase();
        children=new LinkedList<Node>();
    }

    /*
     *  @param      other       Connecting to another Node - adding a child
     */
    public void connectTo(Node other){
        if(!(children.contains(other))&&!(this==other))     children.add(other);    
    }

}
```

The method for generating the connections, where wordDifference is a method which checks that the words are on letter different, returning a boolean based on that test:

```
/*
 *  @param      fW          Finding the links of the inputted String
 */
public void connectionLink(String fW){
    //  dKS=discoveryKeys enum, dK=discoveryKey
    Enumeration<String> dKS=hash.keys();
    while(dKS.hasMoreElements()){               //  Loop checks the word against every other word
        String dK2=dKS.nextElement();
        if(wordDifference(hash.get(fW),hash.get(dK2))){
            (hash.get(fW)).connectTo(hash.get(dK2));
            //  System.out.println("Linking: "+hash.get(fW).getWord()+" & "+hash.get(dK2).getWord());
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. There may not actually be anything wrong with this piece of code, the problem might lie elsewhere, but thanks in advance.

The main problem is that this isn't producing an optimal [shortest path] result - it's going through unnecessary words to get to the goal [as in the example], is there anything wrong with my implementation of breadth-first search [as that should be optimal]?

Comment: Yes, it's for an assignment. It's a data structures module though, not an AI one, so getting this to be optimal isn't going to score me crucial points, but it's something I want to get right if I can. It's either this, or the university's advisory service which helps students with assignments, but I've had so many lectures today I haven't had a chance to visit them D:

Comment: I was going to say you should tag it as such, but it seems that is a thing of the past.

Comment: However, what is your question? All I can find is that there might not be anything wrong with this code and that any help would be appreciated, not what you want us to help with or what the program is doing wrong.

Comment: The question is 'is there any reason why this code is not producing an optimal result? As with the example & missing out the unnecessary words. Breadth-first search should be optimal, & my implementation isn't.'

Comment: And how is optimal defined in that context?

Comment: @OlegOstroumov Appended it to the question.

Comment: It has no `getConnections()` method.
edit: Ah, I suppose it returns `children`.

And please post `connectionLink` code

Comment: @OlegOstroumov I stated that it has standard getters & setters for its variables, I took them out so not to make it too massive a post & they're pretty obvious, Eclipse generated ones.

Comment: When a word occurs two times, do we get the same Node object twice or do we get different Node Objects both having their `word` set to the same value? (No, this alone shouldn't pose a problem, but it opens up doors for other problems (possibly outside the code you showed us) to end up giving you inefficient results instead of just downright failing or something like that.

Comment: @Jasper The dictionary data files the program uses are `grep`'d from UNIX system dictionaries so there's no repeating words, that prevents any duplicates in the graph.

Comment: @Jasper Ah, sorry, misread your query, it actually links the Node already in the Hashtable - an already existing object.

Comment: I think the bug might well be in the implementation of `connectionLink()`. Could you wrapping it with `if (!current.getVisited()){` and `}` and see if that changes anything? (if I'm right, it will give a different solution to the problem described above, very possibly the "no connection found" solution, but it's also possible it'll just find another (longer?) connection).

Comment: it's already inside the if statement you suggested, it's a bit wider than you suggest - trying that returns the 'no connection found'. I'll add my method for `connectionLink()` to the question, I think that method's fairly solid though. Thanks for taking the time to look at my code so far!